# Идентификатор "ch" не определён. В чём ошибка?

Tags: c++, область-видимости

По-моему, код должен работать, но visual studio считает иначе

```
int main()
{
    do
    {
        int shift;
        string word, originalWord;
        char ch;

        system("cls");

        cout << "Enter your word, that you are wont to encrypt: " << endl;
        cin >> originalWord;

        cout << "1 - cipher of Caesar (russian version (doesn't work correctly))" << endl;
        cout << "2 - cipher of Caesar (english version)" << endl;
        cout << "3 - exchange 'begin - the end' (russian version (doesn't work correctly))" << endl;
        cout << "4 - exchange 'begin - the end' (english version)" << endl;

        ch = _getch();

        switch (ch)
        {
            case 49: cipherOfCaesarRussian(word, shift); break;
            case 50: cipherOfCaesarRussian(word, shift); break;
            //case 51: cipherExchangeBeginToTheEndRussian(word); break;
            //case 52: cipherExchangeBeginToTheEndEnglish(word); break;
        }

        cout << "Continue?" << endl << endl << "Yes - press 'Enter'" << endl << "No - press 'Esc'";

        ch = _getch();
    } while (ch != 27); // Пока не нажата клавиша Esc

    _getch();

    return 0;
}
```

После строки   `while (ch != 27)` компилятор выдаёт

> "идентификатор "ch" не определён"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто объявите `ch` до цикла, в начале функции `main` например, тогда ваша переменная будет видна во всех последующих (не факт) блоках функции `main` и на запись и на чтение.

Comment: Почему не факт? Переменная будет видна ниже точки объявления во всем блоке, где она объявлена (т.е. во всей функции main).

Comment: @insolor, да, кроме тех ситуаций когда мы переопределяем переменную в блоке на уровень ниже, по этому я подметил это.

Answer (score 4):

Ну правильно - он определен в теле цикла, и на скобке `}` перед `while` его область видимости и заканчивается...

Так что прав Visual Studio...